# Exporting "pennLC" object stored in R as a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, r

I need to export the `pennLC` object from `package:SpatialEpi` as a shapefile. `pennLC`  contains different components of lung cancer dataset for Pennsylvania state such as:

- `$geo`, a data frame
- `$data`, a data frame
- `$smoking`, a data frame
- `$spatial.polygon`, SpatialPolygons.

The problem is, `pennLC` has a number of components which won't be linked together when I try to export them as different tables and shapefiles using `writeOGR` or `writeSpatialShape` commands.

I need `pennLC` object exported out of R as a shapefile in a way that its datasets/components are tied together.

Comment: How did you get or create `pennLC`? What sort of object is it? What size are those dataframes, and how do they relate to the SpatialPolygons? I don't think we can do this from what you've given us. Please expand. Using the `str` function on R objects can tell you about the structure of an object, and the `head` function can show us the top few lines of data frames. Post a few of those outputs into your question.

Comment: If you'd written your post carefully and included `library(SpatialEpi); data(pennLC)` at the top then we wouldn't have wasted our time. ?? won't find it unless SpatialEpi is installed which means you expect people to search R documentation on the internet every time someone uses a name they don't recognise? Much easier for you to tell us its in SpatialEpi (there's also a copy supplied with RgoogleMaps, FYI)

Comment: Yah you're right, I am sorry I did not mean to waste your time. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the rows of a data frame and a SpatialPolygons object line up, it is trivial to create a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame and export that to a shapefile. For the `pennLC` data, this is easy enough for the `$geo` and `$data` components, because they have 67 rows, one for each county.

First check the county names line up:

```
> all(names(pennLC$spatial.polygon) == pennLC$smoking$county)
[1] TRUE
> all(names(pennLC$spatial.polygon) == pennLC$geo$county)
[1] TRUE
```

Then its okay to do:

```
> pennLC_s = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
   pennLC$spatial.polygon,
   data=cbind(pennLC$geo, pennLC$smoking),
   match.ID=FALSE)
```

and then you can create a shapefile with `writeOGR` (or easier still, the `shapefile` function from the `raster` package).

The tricky thing is the `$data` element, which has 16 rows per county, being cases and population broken down by 4 age groups, 2 race groups, and 2 gender groups (4x2x2=16). This is going to give us 32 columns. The problem now is to rearrange this data frame into what's called "wide" format.

For this we use the `melt` and `dcast` functions from the `reshape2` package

```
> require(reshape2)
> df = dcast(melt(pennLC$data), county~age+race+gender+variable) 
Using county, race, gender, age as id variables
> dim(df)
[1] 67 33
```

This is our data reshaped, so now we have 67 rows (one for each county) and 33 columns (a county column, and 16 count and 16 population columns).

The names are constructed from the factors in the original data:

```
> names(df)
 [1] "county"                  "40.59_o_f_cases"        
 [3] "40.59_o_f_population"    "40.59_o_m_cases"        
 [5] "40.59_o_m_population"    "40.59_w_f_cases"        
 [7] "40.59_w_f_population"    "40.59_w_m_cases"        
 [9] "40.59_w_m_population"    "60.69_o_f_cases"
```

and you may have trouble with the name length limit in shapefiles shortly... lets proceed. Check the names line up:

```
> all(df$county==names(pennLC$spatial.polygon))
[1] TRUE
```

now make a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame:

```
> pennLC_data = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(pennLC$spatial.polygon, df, match.ID=FALSE)
```

and write it (to my `/tmp` folder, you write it where you want it) using `raster::shapefile`:

```
> require(raster)
> shapefile(pennLC_data, "/tmp/penn.shp", overwrite=TRUE)
Warning message:
In writeOGR(x, filename, layer, driver = "ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = overwrite,  :
  Field names abbreviated for ESRI Shapefile driver
```

The names have been a bit mashed, you might benefit from making the column names shorter before writing it:

```
> ogrInfo("/tmp","penn")
Source: "/tmp", layer: "penn"
Driver: ESRI Shapefile number of rows 67 
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
Extent: (-80.53494 39.72316) - (-74.72516 42.26137)
CRS: +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +no_defs  
LDID: 87 
Number of fields: 33 
         name type length typeName
1       conty    4     80   String
2  40_59__f_c    0     10  Integer
3  40_59__f_p    0     10  Integer
4  40_59__m_c    0     10  Integer
5  40_59__m_p    0     10  Integer
6  40_59_w_f_    0     10  Integer
7  40_59_w__1    0     10  Integer
8  40_59_w_m_    0     10  Integer
```

OR use a better format than a shapefile.